# Swift blink UIButtons (not on tap)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a simon memory game in swift where the 4 buttons blink in sequence and user has to memorize the sequence and guesses. Right now I'm generating random sequence of something like [Green, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow] and as I'm generating these I want to make the green button blink, then red, then green, and so on. How do I do this?

```swift
    @IBOutlet weak var green: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var red: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yellow: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var blue: UIButton!
```

```swift
    enum Block {
        case green
        case red
        case yellow
        case blue
    }

    //Block button action
    @IBAction func greenButton() {
        if playerTurn && (blocksPressed < signals.count ){
            blocksPressed += 1
            guesses.append(Block.green)
            guess()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func redButton() {
        if playerTurn && (blocksPressed < signals.count) {
            blocksPressed += 1
            guesses.append(Block.red)
            guess()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func yellowButton() {
        if playerTurn && (blocksPressed < signals.count) {
            blocksPressed += 1
            guesses.append(Block.yellow)
            guess()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func blueButton() {
        if playerTurn && (blocksPressed < signals.count ){
            blocksPressed += 1
            guesses.append(Block.blue)
            guess()
        }
    }
```

```swift
    let randomSource = GKARC4RandomSource() //for random number generation
    var signals:[Block] = []

    func giveSignal() {
        disableButton()
        signals = []
        for _ in 0...levelNum  {
            let randomSignal:Int = randomSource.nextInt(upperBound: 4)
            switch randomSignal {
                //Green
                case 0:
                    signals.append(Block.green)
                //Red
                case 1:
                    signals.append(Block.red)
                //Yellow
                case 2:
                    signals.append(Block.yellow)
                //Blue
                case 3:
                    signals.append(Block.blue)
            default:
                break
            }

        }
        let finalSeq:String = makeString()
        statusBar.text = finalSeq
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo code.

There are two parts.

**Firstly**, The animation. You should use the KeyFrame animation.

Here is the corresponding [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframeswithduration?language=objc)

**Secondly**, The signals of Block enums ,you should consume it.

Here is a little tricky, algorithm somewhat.

a `switch case` fits you.

```
       let blink: (Block) -> Void = {(option) in
            switch option {
            case .green:
                self.green.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            case .red:
                self.red.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            case .yellow:
                self.yellow.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            case .blue:
                self.red.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            }
        }


        let total: TimeInterval = 1.2

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: total, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
            let proportion: TimeInterval = 0.25
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: total * proportion * 0, relativeDuration: total * proportion) {
                blink(self.signals.removeFirst())
            }
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: total * proportion * 1, relativeDuration: total * proportion) {
                blink(self.signals.removeFirst())
            }

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: total * proportion * 2, relativeDuration: total * proportion) {
                blink(self.signals.removeFirst())
            }

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: total * proportion * 3, relativeDuration: total * proportion) {
                blink(self.signals.removeFirst())
            }

        }) { (_) in }
```

Comment: are blinks and UIView.animateKeyframes functions? where should i put them.. also I get many errors

Comment: blinks are closure, Anonymous function. Show your error in the question, I will solve it